# Why there is a performance issue when using bigquery using pandas read_sql?

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I was running a query on a dimension table(year_id, year) to fetch 4 rows using google cloud console and got the result in 0 seconds. It took me 3+ seconds when I use pandas read_sql. Is it due to network latency or something else?

Comment: I woud suggest latency.. The console should be optimised for BigQuery.

Comment: So is there any way to get the query results in minimum time? Getting such a small table result in 3 seconds for an application is very costly.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `google-cloud-bigquery`

https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/index.html

This is the official python lirary for communicating with GBQ.

It is maintained by Google and can be easily integrated with Pandas

Comment: Thanks. I already tried this and got a similar running time for both. One point I noted here is `query_job = client.query(QUERY)`, if I remove this line and do only `query_job.result()` part then it takes  around 1.5 seconds